# Python Spaced Triangle

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm supposed to write a program that ends up such as this:

```
*     *
 *   *
  * *
   *
```

I have the code written for a regular one, but I'm not sure how to incorporate spaces into it.

```
def triangle(i, t = 0):
    if i == 0
        return 0
     else:
        print ' ' * (t + 1) + '*' * (i * 2 - 1)
        return triangle(i - 1, t + 1)
```

Advice?

Comment: Can you edit it differently? I can't tell at all what you're asking.

Comment: Don't multiply the '\*' or you will get lots of them...  Put another set of spaces in like so:     ' ' \* (t + 1) + '\*' + ' ' \* (i \* 2 - 3) + '\*'           Then you just need another condition to check for when you are at the bottom and print 1 star instead of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def triangle(i, t = 0):
    if i == 0:
        print (t+1) *' '+ '*'

    else:
        print ' ' * (t + 1)+ '*' + ' ' * (i * 2 - 1) + '*'
        triangle(i - 1, t + 1)

triangle(5)
```

this code print:

```
 *         *
  *       *
   *     *
    *   *
     * *
      *
```

Comment: You actually don't need the return statements because you aren't using the result of your recursive function.  Just change `return triangle(i - 1, t + 1)` to `triangle(i - 1, t + 1)` and remove `return 0`, also change i == 0 to i <= 0 to prevent an infinite loop if you pass a negative value

Answer (score 2):

Let's label some areas in a line:

```
startSpaces   *   middleSpaces   *   endSpaces
```

For a given line you want `startSpaces` + 1 + `middleSpaces` + 1 + `endSpaces` to equal a constant. This constant is `2*(i+t) + 1`

line 1 will have `t=0` spaces before the `*`
the final line will have `t=i` spaces before the `*` (here I'm using the original `i`, I know it changes through recursion)

So can you find a pattern for `startSpaces`, `middleSpaces` and `endSpaces` that will give you the proper pattern?

Keep in mind that you will need an additional `else if` case for `i==1` so that you can handle the row with only one `*`

Comment: in addition, you're missing a colon in the first 'if' statement, and your else statement is at the wrong indentation

Answer (score 2):

Building on @kharazi's answer (because this reminds me of my early GWBasic programming which is what got me excited about programming as a kid):

```
def triangle(i, leftShape='*', rightShape='*', bottomShape='*', spaceShape=' ', t = 0):
    if i <= 0:
        print ((t+1)*spaceShape)+bottomShape+((t+1)*spaceShape)
    else:
        print (spaceShape*(t + 1))+leftShape+(spaceShape*(i*2-1))+rightShape+(spaceShape*(t + 1))
        triangle(i-1, leftShape, rightShape, bottomShape, spaceShape, t+1)

if __name__== '__main__':
    triangle(3)
    triangle(3, '\\', '/')
    triangle(3, '\\', '/', '~')
    triangle(5, '╚╗', '╔╝', '╚╦╝')
    triangle(5, '╚╗', '╔╝', '╚╦╝', '|')
    triangle(-2)
```

Produces the following output:

```
triangle(3)
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *

triangle(3, '\\', '/')
 \     /
  \   /
   \ /
    *

triangle(3, '\\', '/', '~')
 \     /
  \   /
   \ /
    ~

triangle(5, '╚╗', '╔╝', '╚╦╝')
 ╚╗         ╔╝
  ╚╗       ╔╝
   ╚╗     ╔╝
    ╚╗   ╔╝
     ╚╗ ╔╝
      ╚╦╝

triangle(5, '╚╗', '╔╝', '╚╦╝', '|')
|╚╗|||||||||╔╝|
||╚╗|||||||╔╝||
|||╚╗|||||╔╝|||
||||╚╗|||╔╝||||
|||||╚╗|╔╝|||||
||||||╚╦╝||||||

triangle(-2)
 *
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be using a for loop for this, recursion works but it is not the best idea to use it all the time. this is what i did:

```
def GioTri(i):

foo = i - 1
bar = 0

for i in range(i-1):


    print ' ' * bar + "*" + " " * (foo*2 - 1) + "*" + " " * bar
    foo = foo - 1
    bar = bar + 1


print " " * bar + "*" + " " * bar
```

the result of this looks like this:

```
*     *
 *   * 
  * *  
   *
```